# Determine the Apex class's namespace

Tags: apex

I need to generate a URL for my RestResource, including the correct namespace.  We've been moving the code between an org without a name space, and another org with a temporary namespace.  I'd like to write the code so it will work properly during all stages of development, including release.

My current solution is to use a `DescribeSObjectResult` for one of our custom objects, and compare the `getName()` value to `getLocalName()`:

```
global static String namespace()
{
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult D = MyCustomObject__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
    return D.getName().removeEnd( D.getLocalName()).removeEnd( '__');
}
```

Is there a simpler way to get the namespace?

**Update**

Based on Axaykumar Varu's answer, I am now using the following:

```
/*
    Retrieve our namespace.  Returns Null or the namespace without any adornment.
*/
public static String namespace()
{
    ApexClass ac = [SELECT NameSpacePrefix 
                    FROM ApexClass
                    WHERE Name = 'MyClassName'];
    return ac.NameSpacePrefix;
}
```

The only downside of this current code is that I've had to hard-code the 'MyClassName' portion of the query.  I'm not aware of a way to automatically use the name of the class that the code appears in.

Comment: As for your `namespace()` method, you could add the class name as a parameter so that it could be used to get any class' namespace

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Salesforce provides a standard object called [ApexClass](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexclass.htm), by using this object you can get the Namespace.

Query on ApexClass:

`ApexClass ac = [SELECT NameSpacePrefix FROM ApexClass WHERE Name = 'YourClassName'];`

Comment: Using the difference between getName and getLocalName is safer since there could be conflicts on YourClassName across packages (or unpackaged code).

Answer (score 7):

The [UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed(String)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) method can be used for this without a SOQL query.

If the namespace passed in isn't valid in the current org (due to the package not being installed) a TypeException is thrown, which would indicate you're working with an unmanaged version of your codebase.

If the method returns true you're in a managed environment, and false means you're in a managed environment but aren't licensed for the package (which wouldn't happen in the packaging org).

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of the class, try this solution (inspired by [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23998/return-name-of-class-from-instance-of-that-class)):

`String namespace = MyClass.class.getName().split('\\.')[0];`

NOTE: This only works if you for sure are working within a managed package, otherwise you need to check the presence of a dot:

`String namespace = MyClass.class.getName().contains('.') ?  MyClass.class.getName().split('\\.')[0] : '';`