# Return Name of class from instance of that class

Tags: apex, class, reflection

I need a quick approach to something like:

```
  MyClass mc = new MyClass();
  String theName = ClassNameProvider.getName(mc); // returns 'MyClass'
```

Comment: I've upvoted @pbattisson's answer but for some crazy solution (if you'd need the method name too) go check out http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/6171/capturing-process-information-with-apex ;)

Comment: Voting for the idea [Method to get the Type of an Object -also Primitive Type not only SObject](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l9wHAAQ) would be a good long term solution.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think your requirement falls in the gap for apex but we have the ability to do one of following things:

We can retrieve the name of an object using code such as

```
String name = MyClass.class.getName(); //returns MyClass
```

We can check whether the instance of a particular type using

```
Boolean isSame = mc instanceof MyClass; //returns true
```

Or if we want to get the name from an instance of an unknown type we can do:

```
String name = String.valueOf(mc).split(':')[0];//returns MyClass
```

Hopefully one of those covers your need. See the [discussion to a similar question here for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547563/how-do-i-introspect-the-class-of-a-variable-in-apex)

Comment: harder, better, faster, stronger

Comment: NOTE: `String.valueOf(mc).split(':')[0]` will not include the top level class for inner classes

Comment: NOTE: That `String.valueOf(mc)` returns the `toString()` value of the class. The default return value is format of `ClassName:[field1=value1, field2=value2,...fieldN=valueN]` but if the class overrides the `toString()` method then this trick may not work for you.

Comment: Worth considering: `String name = String.valueOf( mc ).substringBefore( ':' )` as it's just a little bit clearer

Answer (score 11):

This is an interesting hack as posted on the idea [Method to get the Type of an Object (also Primitive Type not only SObject)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l9wHAAQ) by [Robert Strunk](https://success.salesforce.com/ProfileView?u=0053000000BKPq3AAH):

```
public static String getObjectType(Object obj){

    String result = 'DateTime';
    try{
        DateTime typeCheck = (DateTime)obj;
    }
    catch(System.TypeException te){

        String message = te.getMessage().substringAfter('Invalid conversion from runtime type ');
        result = message.substringBefore(' to Datetime');
    }

    return result;
}
```

The parse conversion exception approach overcomes the caveat that using `String.valueOf(obj).split(':')[0]` does not work in scenarios where the Apex class' `toString()` method has been overriden and returns a value in a different format, as pointed out in [this comment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23998/return-name-of-class-from-instance-of-that-class#comment336987_24002).

Comment: This method is also better than the `String.valueOf(obj)` method because it includes the top-level class for inner classes.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the title of the question: to get the name of the class from within any class use this:

```
String CurrentClassName = String.valueOf(this).substring(0,String.valueOf(this).indexOf(':'));
```

Comment: Note the accepted answer recommends `String.valueOf(mc).split(':')[0]` among other approaches. This approach is just a slower version of that (you take `String.valueOf` twice).

Comment: Actually, sometimes Paul's answer works better. Split-approach in some cases, for example within a loop, could reach a "Regex is too complicated" Salesforce Limit.

Comment: This could be improved by saving String.valueOf(this) in a string, which is then referenced twice.
But, it beats all the other methods becuase they all need a line with the Class name in it in the first place - just save it as a String if you are going to do that.
This method works, exactly as it is, everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

While my response might be a delayed, it could help for someone currently in search of this solution.

[GitHub Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/thameemKflex/0a4f4125b7115bc11cc83803c66318a1)

Usage :

```
ClassUtility.getClassName(); // will return the class name from where we are calling
ClassUtility.getMethodName(); // will return the method name from where we are calling
 
ClassUtility.getMethodNameByLevelup(1);
ClassUtility.getMethodNameByLevelup(1);
```

Class :

```
/**
 * Company: Kloudflex.com
 * Purpose: A utility class for extracting class and method names from the stack trace.
 * Author: Mohamed Thameem
 * 
 * Change Log:
 * 01/11/2024 - Initial Version of the class
 */

public class ClassUtility {

    /**
    * Gets the class name from the stack trace.
    * @return String - The class name.
    */
    public static String getClassName() {
        List<String> splitClassList = getClassOrMethodName(0);
        return (splitClassList != null) && splitClassList.size() > 1 ? splitClassList[1] : 'Unavailable';
    }

    /**
    * Gets the method name from the stack trace.
    * @return String - The method name.
    */
    public static String getMethodName() {
        List<String> splitMethodList = getClassOrMethodName(0);
        return (splitMethodList != null) && splitMethodList.size() > 2 ? splitMethodList[2] : 'Unavailable';
    }

    /**
    * Gets the class name from the stack trace by moving up a specified number of levels.
    * @param levelUp - The number of levels to move up in the stack trace.
    * @return String - The class name.
    */
    public static String getClassNameByLevelup(Integer levelUp) {
        List<String> splitClassList = getClassOrMethodName(levelUp);
        return (splitClassList != null) && splitClassList.size() > 1 ? splitClassList[1] : 'Unavailable';
    }

    /**
    * Gets the method name from the stack trace by moving up a specified number of levels.
    * @param levelUp - The number of levels to move up in the stack trace.
    * @return String - The method name.
    */
    public static String getMethodNameByLevelup(Integer levelUp) {
        List<String> splitMethodList = getClassOrMethodName(levelUp);
        return (splitMethodList != null) && splitMethodList.size() > 2 ? splitMethodList[2] : 'Unavailable';
    }

    /**
    * Gets the class or method name from the stack trace by moving up a specified number of levels.
    * @param levelUp - The number of levels to move up in the stack trace.
    * @return List<String> - The list containing class and method names.
    */
    private static List<String> getClassOrMethodName(Integer levelUp) {
        levelUp = levelUp == null ? 0 : levelUp;

        try {
            Integer a;
            a = a + 1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            List<String> splitStackTrace = e.getStackTraceString().split('\n');
            String traceString = (splitStackTrace.size() > (2 + levelUp)) ? splitStackTrace[(2 + levelUp)] : null;
            return (traceString != null) ? traceString.split(':').size() > 0 ? traceString.split(':')[0].split('\\.') : null : null;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```