# How to get a runtime list of all fields of a given sObject?

Tags: apex, api, architecture

So, using this I can get populated fields and values for a given sObject:

**[How to get the Runtime-Type of an Object dynamically (for Primitive Data Types and SObjects)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48019/how-to-get-the-runtime-type-of-an-object-dynamically-for-primitive-data-types-a)**

...and I have this working in the debug log.

[image]

However, is there any way to get this for all fields, whether populated or not? (Effectively describing the object given a generic sObject).

Comment: So you want a list of fields for an object?

Comment: The linked question doesn't really seem to have anything to do with what you are asking here.

Comment: @adrian-larson Yes, sorry, had a couple of links and copy-pasted the wrong one.

Comment: @sfdcfox yes. Adrians answer below looks perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the `SObjectType` already:

```
public static List<SObjectField> getFields(SObjectType sObjectType)
{
    return sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values();
}
```

If you just have an `SObject`, you can get its token and pass it to the above:

```
public static List<SObjectField> getFields(SObject record)
{
    return getFields(record.getSObjectType());
}
```