# Can you check the instanceOf an object dynamically?

Tags: apex, reflection

**Updated after several answers and comments, to clarify the requirements**

I have an Open Source library and am looking to implement a method that will check if an object is an instance of a given type.  That type needs to be specifiable as a parameter.

It needs to work throughout hierarchies, and with both SObjects and Objects (although the latter *could* be handled with two different methods).

So, for example:

- Checking a Contact against the type 'Contact' would match.
- Checking a Contact against the type 'SObject' would match.
- Checking a Contact against the type 'Account' would not match.
- Checking an instance of a Class against that Class's type would match.
- Checking an instance of a Class against any of that Class's supertypes or interfaces would match.
- Checking an instance of a Class against 'Object' would match.
- Checking an instance of a Class against 'SObject' would not match.

Because of the requirement to be able to check within the class hierarchy, retrieving the type of an object and comparing it directly to a type cannot be the answer.  In that situation, checking Contact against SObject would fail, when Contact *is* an instance of an SObject.

With `instanceof`, you *can* check if an object is of a particular type.

For example:

```
Sobject con = new Contact();
System.debug( con instanceOf Contact );
// true
```

Whereas the following won't even compile, because, as the compiler says:

```
Contact con = new Contact();
System.debug( con instanceOf SObject );

Operation instanceof is always true since an instance of Contact is always an instance of SObject
```

It feels like what I am looking for is the ability to check the instance of an object against a dynamic type, for example, along the lines of:

```
Sobject con = new Contact();
Type conType = Contact.class;
System.debug( con instanceOf conType );
// true
```

The above doesn't work, but is there an incantation that does?

**Update**

There are some good answers already, but none quite hit the mark, and maybe this isn't possible in Apex (yet).

The issue is that the method I want to write will form part of an Open Source library and so the solution needs to be bulletproof, and ideally work with objects of any type (ideally including primitives).

It may be possible to implement a solution that includes several methods.

E.g.

```
public Boolean isInstanceOfSobject( SObjectType sobjectType )
```

and

```
public Boolean isInstanceOfObject( Type objecttype )
```

But, as I say, it would need to be bulletproof and deal with namespaces, hierarchies and suchlike.

For those interested in why: it would form part of Amoss (an Apex Mocking Framework):

- https://github.com/bobalicious/amoss

And implement an 'instanceOf' parameter checker as per this issue:

- https://github.com/bobalicious/amoss/issues/101

Comment: Actually `getType` method of https://github.com/bobalicious/amoss/blob/main/force-app/amoss_main/default/classes/Amoss_Asserts.cls is good enough. Have you faced any issues working with it?

Comment: No, I haven't, but it doesn't do what I need it to.  For example, Contact is an instance of SObject.  Comparing the types directly would tell you that it isn't.

Comment: Have added more detail to clarify requirements - showing that checking returns from a `getType` method would not work

Comment: You can use my method you can Directly pass `Object` and type like `Boolean.class`

Comment: but you right it will not work with inheritance tree

Comment: but added a separate class with instance method as per specification

Comment: To be clear - any answer that requires the computation of the passed in object's type and then comparing that directly with another *will not work* - it will never check within the hierarchy and so would not meet the requirements.

Answer (score 5):

Not like this, because [`instanceof`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_instanceof.htm) keyword verifies at run time whether an object is actually an instance of a particular **class** but the [`class`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm) property returns the `System.Type` of the type it is called on.

To determine the `SObjectType` of SObject it's enough to call [`getSObjectType()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) on its instance:

```
SObject con = new Contact();
con.getSObjectType(); // Contact
```

To get the `Object` type, since APEX doesn't support reflection, you need to write your own type checker method. Please check [How to get the Runtime-Type of an Object dynamically (for Primitive Data Types and SObjects)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48019/how-to-get-the-runtime-type-of-an-object-dynamically-for-primitive-data-types-a)

```
class TypeChecker {
    static Type getType(Object o) {
        // Check if null
        if (o == null) return null;
        // Check if SObject and not List<SObject>, since List<SObject> is an instance of SObject 
        if (o instanceof SObject && !(o instanceof List<SObject>)) {
            return Type.forName(((SObject) o).getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName());
        }
        // Check if primitive in order of hierarchy
        if (o instanceof Boolean) return Boolean.class;
        if (o instanceof Id) return Id.class;
        if (o instanceof String) return String.class;
        if (o instanceof Blob) return Blob.class;
        if (o instanceof Date) return Date.class;
        if (o instanceof Datetime) return Datetime.class;
        if (o instanceof Time) return Time.class;
        if (o instanceof Integer) return Integer.class;
        if (o instanceof Long) return Long.class;
        if (o instanceof Decimal) return Decimal.class;
        // Parse type from TypeException error message for Collections/Classes
        try {
            Datetime dt = (Datetime) o;
        } catch (TypeException exc) {
            String typeName = exc.getMessage()
                    .substringAfter('Invalid conversion from runtime type ')
                    .substringBefore(' to Datetime');
            return Type.forName(typeName);
        }
        // Unreachable block
        return Object.class;
    }
}
```

Note

- Although `SObject` is not a subclass of `List<SObject>` but `(new List<SObject>() instanceof SObject) == true`;
- For now it seems impossible to distinguish between `Decimal` and `Double`;

Examples:

```java
TypeChecker.getType(new Map<Object, Map<CustomClass.InnerClass, namespace__SObject__c>>()));
// Map<ANY,Map<CustomClass.InnerClass,namespace__SObject__c>>
TypeChecker.getType(new List<SObject>())); // List<SObject>
TypeChecker.getType(new Set<Account>())); // Set<Account>
TypeChecker.getType(new Map<Id, Account>())); // Map<Id,Account>
TypeChecker.getType(new Map<Account, SObject>())); // Map<Account,SObject>
TypeChecker.getType(new Map<Account, Object>())); // Map<Account,ANY>
TypeChecker.getType(JSON.deserializeUntyped('{}'))); // Map<String,ANY>
TypeChecker.getType(JSON.deserializeUntyped('[]'))); // List<ANY>
TypeChecker.getType(JSON.deserialize('{}', Account.class))); // Account
TypeChecker.getType(Type.forName('Object').newInstance())); // System.UnexpectedException
TypeChecker.getType(JSON.deserialize('{}', SObject.class))); // System.UnexpectedException
TypeChecker.getType(new CustomClass())); // CustomClass
TypeChecker.getType(new CustomClass.InnerClass())); // CustomClass.InnerClass
TypeChecker.getType(new APXT_Redlining__Template__c())); // namespace__SObject__c
TypeChecker.getType(new List<SObject>{new Account(), new Contact()})); // List<SObject>
TypeChecker.getType(new InvalidHeaderException())); // System.InvalidHeaderException
TypeChecker.getType((Iterable<Account>) new List<SObject>{new Account()})); // List<SObject>
```

[The idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l9wHAAQ) of using parse conversion `TypeException` approach overcomes the caveats of using `String.valueOf(o).substringBefore(':')`.

for instance:

```java
String.valueOf(new CustomClass()).substringBefore(':'); // "CustomClass" this is fine
String.valueOf(new CustomClass.InnerClass()).substringBefore(':'); // "CustomClass.InnerClass" this is fine too
String.valueOf(new Map<Id, Id>()).substringBefore(':'); // "{}"
String.valueOf(new List<Account>()).substringBefore(':'); // "()"
String.valueOf(new List<SObject>()).substringBefore(':'); // "()"
String.valueOf(new List<Account>{
        new Account(Id = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Account.SObjectType))
}).substringBefore(':'); // "(Account"
```

**PS** Unlike `JAVA` we don't have `java.lang.Object.getClass()` method and approach described above may have pitfalls. There is no other way than determine them empirically and eliminate them... and vote for [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l9wHAAQ).

Comment: Fundamentally, this way of checking does not work - you cannot grab the types and compare them, since this will never match within the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly this is almost possible since Winter '23 using the new Assert class methods:

```
MyObject instance = new MyObject();
Type expectedType = MyOtherObject.class;
Assert.isInstanceOfType(instance, expectedType, 'Object is a different type');
```

The methods work for primitive types, custom classes and SObjects, and appear to treat hierarchies correctly.

Unfortunately AssertExceptions can't be caught, so this is only likely to be useful in tests.

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Assert.htm#apex_System_Assert_isInstanceOfType

Comment: Interesting idea.  Not sure it would work with collections either - E.g. Map<String,Object> doesn't have a .class attribute, does it?  But yes, a very interesting aside for specific use cases.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a more general solution you can do it like this

```
public class CustomClass {

}

public class Plugin {
    public static String getType(Object obj) {

        if (obj instanceof SObject) {
            return ((SObject) obj).getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
        } else if(isPrimitiveType(obj)){
            if(obj instanceof Boolean){
                return 'Boolean';
            } else if(obj instanceof Id) {
                return 'Id';
            } else if(obj instanceof String)   {
                return 'String';
            } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
                return 'Integer';
            } else {
                return 'Decimal';
            }
        } else {
            return String.valueOf(obj).split(':')[0];
        }
    }
    private static Boolean isPrimitiveType(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Integer ||
                obj instanceof String ||
                obj instanceof Decimal ||
                obj instanceof Boolean;
    }

    public Boolean isInstance(Type targetType) {
        return Type.forName(getType(this)) == targetType;
    }

    public static Boolean isInstance(Object obj, Type targetType) {
        return Type.forName(getType(obj)) == targetType;
    }
}



Object customObj = new CustomClass();
Plugin p = new Plugin();
System.debug('###customObj = ' + Plugin.getType(customObj));
System.debug('###account = ' + Plugin.getType(new Account()));
System.debug('###integer = ' + Plugin.getType(4));
System.debug('###decimal = ' + Plugin.getType(4.20));

System.debug('###customObj = ' + Plugin.isInstance(customObj, CustomClass.class));
System.debug('###account = ' + Plugin.isInstance(new Account(), Account.class));
System.debug('###integer = ' + Plugin.isInstance(4, Integer.class));
System.debug('###decimal = ' + Plugin.isInstance(4.20, Decimal.class));

System.debug('###plugin = ' + p.isInstance(Plugin.class));
System.debug('###decimal = ' + p.isInstance(Decimal.class));
```

There is undocumented behavior that for Custom class `String.valueOf` returns name of the class before values.

`isInstance(customObj, CustomClass.class)` returns false in Anononymous because this class is not actually not deployed and Apex is using "anononymous" classes which have different names

**UPDATE**:
added a separate class with instance method

Comment: Fundamentally, this way of checking does not work - you cannot grab the types and compare them, since this will never match within the hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

One way would be this:

```
if(con.getSObjectType() == Schema.Contact.getSObjectType()) {
  // it's a Contact
}
```

UPDATED

The above made sense for the original question, but now that it has been expanded it doesn't cover all the use cases.