# Apex class getSimpleName() equivalent

Tags: apex, class, namespace, method

I would like to get Apex class name without namespace prefix. I wonder if exists any equivalent method like known in Java getSimpleName() ?

Existing method getName() returns apex class name with namespace like follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such reflection is available in `Apex`. If you want to know they type name, you will have to implement it manually.

```
public class MyType
{
    public String getTypeName() { return 'MyType'; }
}
```

Comment: But there are other ways of getting the class name: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23998/return-name-of-class-from-instance-of-that-class

Comment: @renato-oliveira IMHO additional split or substring only for get class name isn't elegant approach.

Comment: Btw. I wonder why getSimpleName() isn't available in Apex which in fact is based on Java lang? How about posting that Idea on Trailblazer Community?

Comment: Because ***Apex does not support reflection***. Not sure why they made that design decision, and I think it would be hard for anyone not working directly on the language to answer that sort of question.

Comment: Thanks @adrian-larson . Also I am confused why exists method `MyApexClass.class.getName()` which in fact returns apex class name, but with namespace prefix.

Comment: @gpoluch Not sure what you are looking at. Classes in my org have no such callable method.

Comment: @adrian-larson please check my updated question